# How to uninstall app downloaded from site with .deb extension?

Tags: apt, deb, software-uninstall, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Linux. I downloaded VS Code from the site having a `.deb` extension and I'm unable to uninstall it. It is not visible in Ubuntu software. It does show in the app drawer and also opens from the terminal by writing `code`. However, if I write `sudo apt-get remove code`, then I get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package code.
```

I have also used purge and also used synaptic package manager it is not visible in there too. I could not find it in the `dpkg --list` too.

[image: screenshots of dpkg --list]
[image: screenshots of dpkg --list]

Comment: You can remove it using the command `sudo dpkg --remove visual-studio-code` or `sudo dpkg --remove code`

Comment: It should show in your packages as `code` if you are using the deb file downloaded from the Microsoft website. However, is there a chance that you may have also installed the [snap version](https://snapcraft.io/code)?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. Also add the output of `type -a code`.

Comment: sorry for delay. i did removed it but none of given methods worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If Visual Studio Code was installed from a .deb package it would be listed in Synaptic package manager, but it is not visible in Synaptic. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove code
```

You can also list all installed snap packages by running `snap list` and check if the code snap package is installed by running `snap list | grep code` .

Answer (score 0):

Install `gdebi`.

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install gdebi
```

Open the original .deb file that you used to install VSCode, using `gdebi`.

The previously shown INSTALL button should now show UNINSTALL. Press it.